# To find root of $x^n+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

If $ \alpha_1,\alpha_n, ....\alpha_n $ be the roots of the equation $x^n+1=0$, then 
$(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(1-\alpha_n)$ is equal to 
a) 1. 
b) 0
c)n
d)2

when I put n=3,and directly evalutae the value of $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(1-\alpha_n)$ I find no option matching to my answer.

I know the answer is 2. i've seen the solution here [If $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$ be the roots of the equation $x^n+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775314/if-alpha-1-alpha-2-ldots-alpha-n-be-the-roots-of-the-equation-xn1).

but, if we put n=3 , $x^3+1$ has roots -1 , and $\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{3i}{2}$
then if we put that in the expression $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(1-\alpha_n)$  , it doesn't give  2. what mistake am i doing ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775314/if-alpha-1-alpha-2-ldots-alpha-n-be-the-roots-of-the-equation-xn1

Comment: but ,if we put n=3 , $x^3+1$ has roots -1 , and $\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{3i}{2}$
then if we put that in the expression $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(1-\alpha_n)$  , it doesn't give  2. what mistake am i doing ?

Comment: @saudade the roots are wrong!, they are : $-1, -\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{i\sqrt{3}}2$

Comment: lord ! thanks . thanks. lol

Comment: There's a sign error. The roots are: $-1, \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. Sum of roots of unit is always 0.

Comment: Hey lab bhattacharjee can you please tell me how to search related questions or give link.